# Javascript Closure Instance confusion

Tags: javascript

I have a large-ish javascript single page app that uses a model / view / controller structure. When data is received from the server, a model is created and it handed to an instance of a view. Every so often, very very rarely, a view is instantiated with a previous version of a model object. Below is a simplified code sample.

```
ObjectA = function (model) {
    var objA = {};
    objA.doTask = function () {
      model.counter += 1;
      if (window.model.created !== model.created){
        console.log("Global model not my instance model");
        debugger;
      }
      console.log(model.version);
    };
    return objA;
};

var model;
model = {version:0, counter:0, created:0};
model.created = new Date().getTime();
window.model = model;


var objAInstance = ObjectA(model);
objAInstance.doTask();

var i, instance;
for (i = 1; i < 100; i+=1) {
  model = {version:i, counter:0};
  model.created = new Date().getTime();
  window.model = model;
  instance = ObjectA(model);
  instance.doTask();
}
```

You would expect this code to print 0-99 to the console, which it does, but sometimes in my app, the model object that doTask modifies is an old version that I would think should be out of scope.

To help track down the problem, I throw what I believe should be the current global model for the app on the window object, and compare creation dates! Sure enough I have old models in my ObjectA instance sometimes!

Does anybody know of some weird caching or optimization that chrome might do that would cause this? Why does it happen so intermittently?

Comment: Did you try using the new operator before ObjectA?

Comment: @Dodekeract, `ObjectA` return object, so not matter use it `new` before or not

Comment: do note that the console is async, and it can run >1 times per MS, or not, so your detection is wonky...

Comment: Okay, is there any reason, why you're not using prototype "classes"? They save memory and kinda just work.

Comment: i not sure, but seems this condition `if (window.model.created !== model.created){` always _false_, because _doTask_ called after `window.model = model;`. And also if `model` global, so it already same `window.model`

Comment: @Jay, can you provide jsfiddle that reproduced your problem?

Comment: Sorry @Grundy, I can't even get a reliable repro in my full app. It only happens perhaps once a day. The code above works as expected every time. Dodekeract, no need for a prototype class as there is only ever one instance of a view.

Comment: @JayKyburz if you see my comment above, code in original post can't work wrong :-) so you need try provide a bit more code from your app

Comment: @Grundy, Thanks for looking at it, I thought it was right but _something_ is wrong. I will add more complexity slowly to see if I can isolate the problem. I use a DOM event to notify the view that there is a new model and that it needs to be recreated so perhaps there is some issues there.